# Insertar registros a tabla relacional en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, backend

Hola soy nuevo en el tema de programación, y tengo el siguiente problema:

:(

Tengo las tablas **Customers**, **Services**, las cuales relacioné **Customers con Services** quedando 1 tabla más...

**Customers_has_Services**

He logrado insertar valores a través de un formulario para las dos tablas (Customers y Services) pero no logro insertar los valores en esta tercera tabla (Customers_has_Services) con valores ya dados a través de PHP, o bien, algo que me facilitaría mucho es que al momento de hacer mi registro del **Customer** y **Services** en automático se relacionen por ID, saben cómo puedo buscar este ejemplo, o ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? Ya que la única forma en la que puedo hacerlo es a través de PHP MyAdmin.

*Tabla de **Customers_has_Services***

[image: Tabla de Customers_has_Services]

Comment: Podrías resolverlo a nivel de BD, usando un procedimiento almacenado y dentro de él un `TRIGGER AFTER INSERT` pero para ello tendrías que tener a mano algún dato que te permita encontrar el id faltante de los dos. Por ejemplo, se inserta un nuevo `Customer`, con `NEW`  obtendrías el ID del mismo en el `TRIGGER`, pero te faltaría el ID de `Service`, sería pasar el dato que tienes a mano al procedimiento almacenado para encontrar ese ID y entonces crearías la nueva fila con los dos valores sin problema. Desde el código PHP simplemente llamarías al SP pasándole el parámetro necesario.

Comment: :( No entendí nada amigo, pensé que sería más fácil hacerlo desde el FORM, pero leeré más de lo que comentas para ver si logro resolverlo D: gracias!

Comment: También lo puedes hacer así. Sería recoger el último ID de cada tabla y usar ambos valores para hacer un `INSERT` en `Customers_has_Services`. Escribe un intento de código y si tienes problemas pregunta aquí. Debes decidir por ejemplo si usarás `mysqli` o `PDO`.